# Having a cell show only the last 8 characters of the text typed in

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

As with all of my Excel work, this is for my job. I work with cars, and we have to keep a log of the VINs that we find exceptions on. Currently we only have the last 8 written down, but I was wondering if there was any way to have it so that the contents of the cell were the full 17 character VIN, but it would only show the last 8?

Comment: What does a typical **VIN** look like??

Comment: 17 digit long, alphanumeric.

Answer (score 2):

Select the cells with the full **VIN** values and run this tiny macro:

```
Sub HideCharacters()
    Dim DQ As String, mesage As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        mesage = Right(r.Value, 8)
        mesage = DQ & mesage & DQ
        r.NumberFormat = ";;;" & mesage
    Next r
End Sub
```

It will not change the values, only how they appear in the cells.

Comment: I suppose this is the best way for it. Thank you.

Comment: The alternative is to use a separate column for the last **8** digits

Comment: Really would rather not